# PFObject subclassing with relationships

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have two classes:

```
@interface RMEvent : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *attachments;
```

and

```
@interface RMFile : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *event;
```

I'm doing this:

```
RMEvent *newEvent = [RMEvent object];
[newEvent pinInBackground];
RMFile *newFile = [RMFile object];
newFile.event = newEvent;
[newFile pinInBackground];
[newEvent addObject:newFile forKey:@"attachments"];
```

and I can see objects are created locally (tested with a query to localDatabase). Everything seems okay.
But then I do (in a lot of different combinations):

```
[newEvent saveEventually];
[newFile saveEventually];
```

and I can't see anything on the server.
How can I save those objects to the server? What is the correct order or maybe I'm doing something wrong in general?

P.S.: I have [self registerSubclass] in each subclass' +load method and I'm instantiating an array in the +object method of RMEvent, so it shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the saveEventually callback for error

```
[newFile saveEventually:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (error) NSLog(error);
}];
```

Is RMFile a PFFile subclass ? If so, you can't saveEventually a PFFile, and can't save an object which as a pointer to a new unsaved PFfile

Edit:
"Found a circular dependency when saving"

Without cloud code :

```
RMEvent *newEvent = [RMEvent object];
RMFile * newFile = [RMFile object];

newEvent[@"newFile"] = newFile;
[newEvent saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        newFile[@"newEvent"] = newEvent;
        [newFile saveEventually];
    }
}];
```

With CloudCode:

```
RMEvent *newEvent = [RMEvent object];
RMFile * newFile = [RMFile object];
newEvent[@"newFile"] = newFile;
[newEvent saveInBackground];
```

And then on a [CloudCode afterSave trigger](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-aftersave-triggers), you can retrieve your RMEvent, get 'newFile' key from it, assign a pointer to newEvent on newFile object, then save newFile

Comment: 1. error: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "Found a circular dependency when saving."
2. RMFile is a subclass of PFObject. I was planning to have a subclass of PFFile also. How to do save with this subclass in the future?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory : When saving and object, Parse starts by saving unsaved child objects. As your child object as itself a pointer to the main-object, when trying to save child, it tries to save main...etc
You should saveInBackground your first object with its child, and then link child to main on callback.
It's generally better to do this in an afterSave function in cloudCode

Comment: can you give me an example? And a bit of explanation for the cloudCode.
You can edit your answer and I will accept it as correct. Thanks!